# decomposition of a representation of a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Here is a theorem:

> Take $L$ a semisimple Lie algebra and $(V,\rho)$ a finite dimensional representation of it.
>
> Define $$V_n = \bigcap_{X\in L}\ker(\rho(X))\\V_r = \sum_{X\in L}\rho(X)V.$$
> Then $V = V_r\oplus V_n$ and both are invariant under $\rho$.

Why is the sum not a problem? This could be an uncountable sum.

Comment: My guess is that, when you wrote “finite”, you meant “finite-dimensional”. Am I right? Besides, what about the sum being uncountable? Why should that be a problem?

Comment: Yes I meant finite dimensional. But I don't see what that changes.
And an uncountable sum is always a problem :-p

Comment: Perhaps that you might explain where the problem is. For instance, if $S^1$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I see nothing wrong with the statement $\mathbb{R}^2=\sum_{v\in S^1}\mathbb{R}v$, in spite of the fact that $S^1$ is uncountable.

Comment: Ok. sorry, I realise that my problem is that I don't know how an uncountable sum is even defined in this case.

Comment: I would have understood if you would have said that you do not understand what an infinite sum means in this context, but why the distinction between countable and uncountable?

Comment: I don't even know what it is for a countable sum :)

Answer (score 0):

If $\{V_i:i\in I\}$ is an indexed family of subspaces of a vector space $V$, then the sum is

$$ \sum_{i\in I}V_i =\mathrm{span}\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i\right) $$

Note we use $\sum$ instead of $\bigoplus$ because the sum may not be direct.